# Two roles in one association (UML diagram)

Tags: associations, uml, diagram

I have never seen two roles in a association relationship in a UML diagram. Is the following appropriate notation, or is there another method of listing two roles?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your diagrams says that `Course` has a property named `1 teaches` of type `Instructor`. And `Instructor` has a property `has a *` of type `Course`.

I guess that the `1` and `*` are multiplicities and they should be placed a bit apart from role names to distinguish them. The remaining role names should rather correspond to what the properties represent. So where currently you see `1 teaches` it should be `teacher` and on the other side there should be `classes` (both with the multiplicities offset).

Comment: Does every binary association require 2 multiplicities and 2 roles?

Comment: Not necessarily. In case you have navigability (your other question) you would eventually have only one role.